# Remove quotes from hash key with expression

Tags: perl, perl-critic

I have:

```
$rejected->{join ',', @needed}++ unless @filtered;
```

but the `perlcritic` complains with

> title=Hash key with quotes - severity 5::[HashKeyQuotes] Avoid useless
> quotes

Obviously I can lower the severity, but I wonder whether there is any other way?

Two which I can think of are:

- use a constant
- move the whole `join` outside the `{}`.

Is there any other approach?

Answer (score 5):

If you get that critic from that code, it's obviously a bug in the `HashKeyQuotes` policy since you don't have useless quotes around hash keys.

[Flag it to be ignored.](https://metacpan.org/dist/Perl-Critic/view/bin/perlcritic#BENDING-THE-RULES) Contorting your code to silence perlcritic defies the whole point of using perlcritic.

Comment: I'm wondering what version their `perlcritic` is, since I don't see this on the latest build.

Comment: I'm taking them at their word about what they got from what code.

Comment: @RawleyFowler perlcritic version 1.152

Comment: Indeed - the point of coding isn't to satisfy perlcritic, and if you don't like a rule or a particular application of a rule, ignore it. I think that particular rule is particularly stupid. Remember, "best practices" aren't unless they have a context, and these rules don't have any context.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's not within PBP to use quotes like that on `join`.  Try:

```perl
$rejected->{join(q{,}, @needed)}++ unless @filtered;
```

I don't see any `perlcritic` warnings with this.

In general though, I would block this on a code review, and ask for you to move the `join` to a new lexically scoped variable, with a decent name.

Comment: I think you refer to [noisy quotes](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic::Policy::ValuesAndExpressions::ProhibitNoisyQuotes)

Comment: I wouldn't make extra code for this, although if the thing got much larger then I would move it out of the braces. Single use variables are also a problem.